# Updating a column on MYSQL with NOW doesn't work properly

Tags: mysql, date, triggers, timestamp, procedure

I need to insert a record on a table with a Now() to measure the time that a trigger consume.
I Have a table named "MyTable" with a trigger (Before Insert) like this:

```
create trigger ...

Set @startTime = NOW();

-- Do complex an expensive operations on the MyTable..

Set @endTime = NOW();

Insert into myLogTable(tableName, Start, End, Creation)
Values ('MyTable', @startTime, @endTime, NOW());
```

The problem is that the table always get the same value in the columns Start, End and Creation, even if a put a Sleep(10) to get a big differences. It's like mysql is chaning the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with a constant value.

myLogTable is filled with something like:

- MyTable - 2015-01-01 10:45:00 - 2015-01-01 10:45:00 - 2015-01-01 10:45:00
- MyTable - 2015-01-02 10:11:10 - 2015-01-02 10:11:10 - 2015-01-02 10:11:10
- MyTable - 2015-01-03 10:55:00 - 2015-01-03 10:55:00 - 2015-01-03 10:55:00

I try with no success with a timestamp function or column, and i always get the same value in the 3 columns.

How can i make a log with the time that the trigger consume in each call?

Comment: The `NOW()` function is operating per the specification; you are describing behavior that is *different* than what it does. Maybe you'll find that the `SYSDATE()` function would be more suited to your purpose. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NOW()` function is evaluated at the *start* of the SQL statement; it returns a value which remains constant for the duration of the SQL statement execution. Every reference to `NOW()` within the statement returns the same value. This same constant value is returned by any references in functions or or triggers that are executed by the statement.

The `SYSDATE()` function is different in that it returns the datetime value when it is executed.

Compare:

```
SELECT NOW(), SLEEP(5), NOW(); 
SELECT SYSDATE(), SLEEP(5), SYSDATE();
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate